# User that tries to delete his posts

Tags: discussion, support

There is an dissatisfied user, he posted already some nonsense answers, that have been already flagged and are now deleted by a moderator.

But now I recognized that he [earned the "Disciplined" badge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707582/nocturn?tab=activity) for deleting a post with score 3 or higher.

Can I find this post somehow (and I assume he deleted more than one of his posts) and vote to undelete or something?

Comment: Why do you think you should undelete it?

Comment: @HenkHolterman if its a try to get rid of all his posts and its a useful answer, then it should be undeleted.

Comment: If it is he/she will be limited and flagged automatically.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you see that a user is rage-quitting, vandalizing posts or deleting own posts with valuable information just flag on of the posts of the user for moderator attention and explain the situation.

In most cases if a user is intentionally destroying content you need to involve a moderator anyway to prevent further vandalism, just undoing it doesn't help if the user can just delete or edit with nonsense again.

Moderators can see deleted posts in a user profile, non-moderators have no way of finding the information you are looking for, they can't search for deleted posts or see them in profiles.

Comment: rage quitting = raging

Answer (score 13):

We're in contact with the user now. Fortunately, the extent of the 'vandalism' was a suggestion that someone solve their problem by *building a reverse a tachyonic flux generator*.

I don't believe the user intended any malice, but rather got frustrated with the guard rails we have in place to prevent content destruction. If you want the attention of a moderator, it's far more productive and convenient (albeit slightly less amusing) to use the flag system.

The community did the correct thing by flagging and I picked up on it rather quickly. It's now a matter that we're handling privately.

**Update**

The issue is now settled. Thanks again to all that brought it to our attention.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was part of those who flagged those answers, but at that point I didn't realized that he already might have deleted some stuff. And you are right, flagging (that I do a lot) is less amusing, because I get much less feedback.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It looked like you picked up on one, then checked, and then pointed out the rest to us. Just by looking at the queue it was pretty obvious what was going on, so indeed very helpful.

Answer (score -2):

If a question has upvoted answers the original user cannot delete it by themselves, so the system prevents loss of good answers contributed by other members.

For those questions with no upvoted answers, we err on the side of allowing the user to delete the posts.  This allow them to remove bad questions which is something to encourage.

There are some questions which are good, with good answers that aren't upvoted that may fall victim to the user deleting them.  That's simply something we have to accept as we balance the user's power to control their content against the good of the community.

Flagging for moderator attention is the best course of action if you believe deletions are hurting the community.

Comment: Still on that Jenny Craig meta-rep diet I see :)

Comment: @TimPost I can't resist!  It's so *slimming!*